# Can I unpack an F# list with no warnings?

Tags: list, f#, pattern-matching

F# makes it easy to unpack tuples. Unpacking lists is also feasible, but the compiler issues a warning:

```
let m = [1; 2; 3]
let [a; b; c] = m
// Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value '[_;_;_;_]' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s)
```

Is there a way to avoid this warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable warnings per file by using the `#nowarn` directive (in your case `#nowarn "25"`) or you can disable warnings on the command line with `--nowarn`.

Check out the [F# Compiler Directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/compiler-directives) for details.

There is currently no way to re-enable warnings again, when first disabled.

Your match may (unexpectedly) result in a runtime error if the number of elements cannot be unpacked to `[a;b;c]`, so instead you can use a complete match that is explicit about the risc:

```
let m = [1;2;3]
let (a,b,c) =
    match m with
    | [a;b;c] -> (a,b,c)
    | _ -> failwith "Expected exactly three items in m"
```

Answer (score 4):

What would happen if your list `m` has 2 or 4 elements?

There is obviously a way, plain old pattern matching:

```
let a, b, c =
   match m with
   | [a;b;c] -> a,b,c 
   | _ -> ... // handle the length!=3 case
```

F# allows you to deconstruct the right-hand side objects that way when there's clear that you only have a single case you need to cover. This is the case with tuples, since there's only one tuple type that would match both the left and the right hand side. Something like this obviously would not compile, because the types won't match:

```
let m = 1, 2 

let a, b, c = m
```

Yet in your case there's no guarantee that you're not in fact in this scenario:

```
let m = [ 1; 2 ]

let [1;2;3] = m
```

You're in fact asking the compiler to allow non-exhaustive pattern matching. You can disable the warning as noted in the other answer, but you're inviting runtime errors that way.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious, but hardly elegant, way is:

```
let m = [1; 2; 3]
let a = List.item 0 m
let b = List.item 1 m
let c = List.item 2 m
```

You can write a helper function to make it neater:

```
let unpack3 x = (List.item 0 x, List.item 1 x, List.item 2 x)

let (a, b, c) = unpack3 m
```

Basically a `list` is not a great fit if you know you are always going to have a fixed number of items.

Comment: You are right about a list not being a great fit in this case. In my "real life" code the list was generated by List.map. Is there a simpler way to convert a list into a tuple? Something like Tuple.ofList()?

Comment: Why not "let myTuple = myList.[0], myList.[1], myList.[2]" ? If that isn't good enough, perhaps you are trying to solve the problem in a not so good way.

Comment: @Soldalma - that would not fit well with the type system, as the return type (e.g. 2-tuple, 3-tuple...) would depend on the contents of the list.